# OAuth Request Token Usage

Tags: authentication, oauth

In the Oauth workflow, why couldn't the consumer key be used directly to identify the consumer to the server while requesting authorization instead of having to use a "Request Token"

Comment: Request tokens can be revoked without having to revoke entire apps

Comment: i don't understand the revoking part. who is revoking? is it the consumer or the server?

Comment: did some realization. please verify if my understanding is correct.

the request token exists to denote the consumers consent for asking authorization.

Comment: 1. image we only assign a consumer a unique code to identify itself. whenever it wants to ask authorization in behalf of a user. it just have to present it's code to the authorization endpoint of the provider.

   e.g: https://api.domain.com/oauth?consumer_key=some_unique_key

with this approach, there is even no need for the consumer key/secret pair to verify the identity of the consumer. there's simply no authentication between the consumer and the provider.

the disadvantage of this approach is that anyone can use the key of the consumer (which is basically available publicly).

Comment: 2. using a request token, the consumer communicates to the provider beforehand of its intention to ask authorization from someone. At this point, the provider nor the consumer doesn't know yet the identity of the user who will grant access.

using this approach, there is consent from the consumer of the authorization process.

Comment: I don't know if my understanding make sense. Feel free to comment on my idea.